# What kind of cooking knife is this?

Tags: equipment, knives

In a show *(One Piece)*, the character uses the following kitchen knife. I've never seen anything like it before; what is it?

[image: One Piece Knife]

Here it is in action:

[image: In Action]

Comment: It looks like a variation of a one-handled mezzaluna ... but I want to say that I've seen something similar to it being used for asian cut noodles.  (I just can't recall if it was Japanese, Chinese, Korean or something else)

Comment: I'm not convinced that knife is a traditional knife of any kind.  I suspect that the artist made it up to look wierd & cool.

Comment: @FuzzyChef : you're rather dismissive.  Are you familiar with cleavers for soba noodles?  The blade often extends to the end of the handle  (although it's not attached).  The overall blade shape reminds me more of a chinese butcher's knife, though.  I suspect it'd be for repetitive slicing more than chopping (better control by having your hand in the middle, but you don't get the leverage)

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee : what's the show?  And what type of kitchen does the character work in?

Comment: Joe: it looks kind of like someone combined a Thai cleaver with a Korean noodle cutter.  But, like I said, I've never seen such a knife (and I've been in cookware stores in several Asian countries) and I can't find images of any matching knife on the internet.  Given that it's animation, the most likely conclusion is that the artist made up the knife to look exotic and/or old-fashioned.

Comment: Here's the two knives I'm talking about: https://www.japanny.com/collections/all/soba-knife  https://shopthailandonline.com/product/12-7-1-4-circle-blade-thailand-knives/  You could combine them and get that knife, but it wouldn't be *useful* for anything.

Comment: Are you sure it is a knife? Could it be a dough scraper instead? This shape is not very functional for cutting. Because of the super straight edge for most of the length, it is unsuited for the rocking style of cutting, which is usually the reason for placing the handle there. The slicing style should work, but after mimicking the motion with a piece of cardboard I cut out, I can say it is awkward, and seems that even after getting accustomed, it will still be less precise than a standard chef knife.

Comment: Rumtscho: why would a dough scraper have a sharpened edge, though?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/73443/what-is-the-name-of-this-style-of-knife

Comment: @Joe Kind of looks like Avatar: The Last Airbender to me

Comment: @Joe It's from the show One Piece

Comment: @FuzzyChef For context, I've added a gif of the knife in action (https://gph.to/2CfZSFH)

Comment: @rumtscho Right, it's not used with a rocking style. Here is a gif for context: https://gph.to/2CfZSFH

Comment: It looks like it sort of resembles a trench knife (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trench_knife#/media/File:M1918_Trench_Knife.jpg), to me, especially since it's got the katana-style wavy grain pattern. It's possible that it's primarily intended as a combat knife, and they're just pressing it into use in a kitchen. Does the character in question ever use it to fight with?

Answer (score 6):

### An ulu knife

That looks like a variant on an [ulu knife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulu), a knife whose blade is below the handle.
[image]

Comment: I've always seen ulu with a curved blade.  (much like a mezzaluna)  Even the [asymetrical ones](https://fishcreekalaska.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=6448) that I managed to find tended to be more rounded than the "kitchen axe" type blade in the image

Comment: This seems to be used very similar to the animation in the question: https://youtu.be/8dF5pz43dGE?t=34 (34 seconds into the video)

Answer (score 3):

After seeing that GIF, I am 99% sure the animator thought up the design by themselves, probably to add some element of interest to the show, but without thinking about the practical side at all.

The animation shows the knife being used in a chopping motion, like a cleaver. But here is what a cleaver looks like

[image]

And this video can be used as a reference for proper use of a cleaver. We see slicing, chopping and rocking motions:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wvt5-iC3xos

The knife in the anime is inferior to the cleaver shown above.

1. It is more difficult to produce. Instead of producing a single continuous piece of steel, you have to punch a hole in it, without cutting through the side.
2. A cleaver needs some weight. And much of its weight comes not from the thin blade, but from the back, which is thicker than on a Western knife. Making a cutout in that place is counterproductive.
3. A cleaver profits from the lever effect. This is especially noticeable in other tools which are used with the same motion, such as axes. But it plays some role in knife cleavers, too. This effect is completely lost in the design shown here.
4. A cleaver is held with the ulna and radius at relatively small angle to the handle, upper arm hanging in its natural position, the lower arm almost parallel to the table. This allows for smooth, precise movement. The design of this knife means that the upper arm is held parallel to the table, and the lower arm goes orthogonal to the table's plane,  creating a very awkward position, which is probably also very tiring if you do lots of cutting. You can even see this terrible position in the GIF. This doesn't matter much in mezzalunas and other similar tools which are used with a rocking motion from the wrist, but this kind of chopping looks like a repetetive strain injury waiting to happen.

Considering these design problems, I hope nobody has had the idea of actually produce such a knife and use it in a real kitchen.

Comment: Also, what the heck is the point on the knife supposed to be for?  Try to imagine any motion you could conceivably make that would bring that point to bear.  You can't do it, not with a human arm.

Comment: Great explanation! The motion did seem awkward to me, but I didn't realize just how impractical such a knife would be. However, the Ulu knife that @greenstone-walker mentioned seems to be used very similar to the animation: https://youtu.be/8dF5pz43dGE?t=34 (see 34 seconds into the video).

Comment: @fuzzychef I guess I didn't think of that because I don't use the point of a chef's knife either, but you are right that if somebody wants to use it - and apparently it is used in a cleaver - it is difficult to impossible.

Comment: @languagesnamedaftercoffee interesting, I had never seen an ulu knife before. I imagined it to be intended for rocking due to the shape. But it is smaller than I thought, and your video shows clearly that it can be gripped conveniently.

Comment: I agree, this knife in it's present shape looks like a cross between a ulu and cleaver.  The only way to use this particular knife would be as an ulu, which is meant to have the object being cut much lower than you.  In most cases it would be meat, and it would be on the ground and the user would be kneeling over the meat.  This would give the user the proper mechanical advantage and maximize hand positioning on the knife.

Answer (score 3):

Your image is an artist's rendition, but it's close to a knife my father used to have, very similar to these images:

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/464926361542917833/

The one we have was made in Seki, Japan.   It's described as a Delphic knife, but googling that name pulls multiple images and history, so I suspect that's the maker, not the type of knife.

I've never seen one with a point on the end, only with a flat tip like these images.   This one below is narrower than the one I grew up with, but it shares the Delphic brand name and general shape.

[image: Delphic curved blade]

Comment: Thank you! So the shape and the motion was drawn completely wrong in the cartoon. This all makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

It looks a bit like a stylized menkiri knife, used for cutting udon noodles. Here is a picture:

[image: picture of menkiri knife]

[Jeffrey Thompson's blog](https://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2012/10/06/menkiri-bocho/) has a picture of the knife in action. Thompson explains:

> The menkiri bocho, also known as the udon kiri, is a knife for slicing handmade noodles – note the inset and the sharpened front edge.  Simply squishing the blade down will not make proper noodles, so the very sharp knife is drawn across to ensure a clean cut.

A [Google Images](https://images.google.com/) for "menkiri knife" brings up several photographs that look similar to the knife in the clip. None look exactly like that knife, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is way too long for a comment, but not exactly an answer as I don't know the name for the knife.

...

Unlike what rumtscho has suggested, the general shape of the knife *is* well known.  It's goes by a few names, but you can find pictures looking for a "Chinese pork knife" or "Chinese slaughter knife" on english language search engines.  It's rather reminiscent of a "straight back" hunting/skinning knife, but deeper.

It's basically a meat cleaver with a front tip that's more like a skinning knife.  [Foodal describes the shape of the Dalstrong Ravager](https://foodal.com/kitchen/knives-cutting-boards-kitchen-shears/things-that-cut/best-meat-cleavers/#Dalstrong) as:

> The Ravager’s 9-inch blade is engineered with a pointed tip, designed to assist with skin removal and to access tight, deep spots that a square tip can’t.

Although the proportions are different, the combination of a long straight section and an upswept tip aren't all that different from some western butcher's knives, particularly the "scimitar" style ones.  The asian knives depth would make them more "cleaver" than "knife" by western standards.

But none of those knives have the handle placement of the knife in the image.  That would be more similar to a Japanese noodle knife (sobakiri, udonkiri, menkiri) in which the blade extends back under the handle, possibly even past the end of the handle.  But those want a long cutting edge, and so aren't curved at the front.

And none of those connect back to the handle at the end.  That would be more like an Inuit ulu, but those don't have the flattened section for slicing on a board.  (although you can get them in a set with a board that's dished out)  But it's often sold on hunting sites as a 'skinning' knife, which is a similar function to what the front of the pork knife is for.

And there's a now-deleted answer from Nova_Super that showed a picture of [a knife being used to cut ice cream on an anti-griddle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mnf5se2b4Ic) that has that connected handle, but doesn't have the rounded tip like a knife for skinning / butchering:

[image: Chinese ice cream vendor's knife]

From my experience from trying to recreate costumes and props from animated shows for cosplay -- I suspect that although I can't find the exact same blade, that it is *not* an invention of the animator.  Modern animators often get real people to dress up and perform actions that are filmed so they have reference material.  The coloration and shape of the blade looks similar to the Chan Chi Kee butcher's knife and 'scraping' knives (dark on the flat / above the grind line, light on bevil), and it's possible that someone used a similar shape blade and modified it to move the handle ... but it's more likely that a prop buyer went looking for the most unusual knife they could find, and found what looks to be a blend of a pork knife and the ice cream knife.

Comment: The knives you list aren't the same shape. Take for example the ravager, the whole blade is clearly in front of the handle. A chef would use the ravager with a chopping motion, swinging your underarm from the elbow while the upper arm stays motionless. The animated knife has the handle in the middle of the blade's back. That has to be used with an up-and-down motion starting from the shoulder, like operating a bicycle pumps with a crossbar handle one-handed. It would be not only exhausting, but also a very awkward angle for the arm, losing a lot of fine motor control.

Comment: Now that userLTK posted a new answer, I think the anime artist must have tried to draw the knife from their picture. So for me, the mystery is solved.

Comment: @rumtscho : you really think it’s just confusion over some other slightly similar knife?  It’s way more likely that there is an exact match that we just haven’t found yet