# Does anyone know the name of the knife this ice cream seller is using?

Tags: knives

Here is an example of the knife being used.

[ASMR - Energy Ice Cream Rolls Oreo | How To Make An Energy Drink Out Of Ice Cream || Chinese Food](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mnf5se2b4Ic)

[image]

Notice it is similar but like a cleaver. I have also been trying to find the name of this, but the closest I found was a Japanese menkiri.

Hope someone can answer this.

PS: it is similar to the knife that was used by BanBan from one piece anime, which was asked by another user.
[What kind of cooking knife is this?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/95538/what-kind-of-cooking-knife-is-this/114724#114724)

Updates:

I just found a clearer view of the knife at 3:58 in the video in the youtube link. Basically, it is like a cleaver, without the handle jutting out, but part of the blade it self.
[image]

It should look something like this:
I tried to use google image search, using this image, to find but no luck.
[image]

PS: The photo above is photoshop of what I think the cleaver looks like.

Comment: It doesn't look like a knife, it looks like a dough scraper.

Comment: There is actually a similar question asking about a similar type of knife: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/73443/what-is-the-name-of-this-style-of-knife/114748#114748 , and I found out the name of the brand is "YAX" which is from Japan but it is a vintage type of knife. But it is still not the one I was looking for.

Comment: I tried taking your mock-up and running it through various reverse image search engines (https://www.duplichecker.com/reverse-image-search.php), but had no luck.  You might try changing the handle placement and try again -- on the left of the handle, the top of the metal aligns with the bottom of the wooden handle, not the top.  (I suspect Baidu is likely best for this ... but I just got a page that translated to "Could not find information about the picture")

Comment: @GdD aren't dough scrapers curved?

Comment: I'd go to a restaurant supply company with the picture, and ask them.

Comment: That's a scraper, not a knife, as in it doesn't have a sharp edge.  That doesn't put you any closer to finding one, though.

Comment: @RonJohn, any luck?

Comment: "I'd go to a restaurant supply company with the picture, and ask them" *if I were motivated to know what that knife is.*

Comment: I agree with @FuzzyChef. It's neither a knife nor a cleaver. It looks like a dough cutter. May I ask for what purpose you are looking for the name or the object itself?

Answer (score 1):

I also believe the style of knife you're looking for is called an "ulu" though the OP pix look to be a ulu cleaver.

Here is an ulu more similar to the OP pix: https://www.kitchenknivesonline.com/products/12-ulu-chef-knife-walnut

[image: Ulu knife]

Answer (score -2):

Might be a [effort saving knife](https://promithi.com/collections/cleaver/products/promithi-chinesisches-hackmesser-kochmesser-kuchenmesser-metzger-fleisch-gemuseschneiden-fleischmesser-ausbeinmesser-obstmesser-santokumesser-schalmesser-allzweckmesser-hackbeil-messer).

[image: effort saving knife]

Or a Ulu knife, as you have noted in the other question. This one is a GH5074 Gil Hibben Knives Legacy Ulu Knife.
[image: GH5074 Gil Hibben Knives Legacy Ulu Knife]

Comment: That looks **nothing** like OP's knife: the handle position and orientation is completely different.